# How to automatically hide rows in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have an attendance tracker that I use to send out an end of shift report. Currently, my entire class's attendance show. I'd like to make a macro that hides rows with 0 time missed.

Blank Tracker 2.0 is the name of the book
Pulse Template is the name of the worksheet I need the macro for
F is the column in which I record time missed (drawn from another sheet)
18-46 are the rows that need to be either hidden or unhidden.

So if F18 is 0, I need it to be hidden. If F18 > 0, I need it visible.

I figure this is a fairly simply macro but I have essentially no experience with macros whatsoever.

Comment: Why not use a filter?  You could try recording a macro while you apply that filter, and that will get you most of the way there.

Comment: Stack Overflow is here to help find coding solutions. To get responses, post attempts you have made. You need to do the heavy lifting yourself.

Answer (score 1):

An efficient way is to use `Union` to gather all the rows to hide and then hide all in one go. Also, this code checks the values are actually numeric in cells.

You can tie this to a [form](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Assign-a-macro-to-a-Form-or-a-Control-button-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283) control or [ActiveX](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/75065-assigning-macro-activex-command-button.html) button as mentioned in prior answer.

```
Sub hideRows()


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Sheet7")

Dim loopRange As Range
Dim currRow As Range
Dim hideRange As Range

Set loopRange = wsSource.Range("F18:F46")
loopRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False

For Each currRow In loopRange.Rows

    If IsNumeric(currRow.Value2) And currRow.Value2 = 0 Then

        If Not hideRange Is Nothing Then
            Set hideRange = Union(currRow, hideRange)
        Else
           Set hideRange = currRow
        End If

    End If

Next currRow

If Not hideRange Is Nothing Then hideRange.EntireRow.Hidden = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

```
Sub HideRowsLoop()
    For Each cell In Worksheets("Pulse Template").Range("C18:C46")
        If cell.Value = "0" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this on a activeX button event. If F18 to F46 is 0, it hides, if not, it shows.

```
Sub button_click()
    Dim i as integer
    For i = 18 to 46
        If Activesheet.Range("F" & i) = 0 Then
            Activesheet.Range("F" & i).entireRow.Hidden = True
        else
            Activesheet.Range("F" & i).entireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much QHarr and pokemon_Man! Really appreciate the coding! Was hoping for a macro that was buttonless but this will do just fine :-)

Comment: please select this answer if it solved your question. thank you.